# I am getting null value in Gridview Datakey. I have loaded Grid through javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want to select a record from Grid that will redirect me to a detail form right now when I select a record it gives me dull value in Gridview.SelectedValue.
                                             
                                                
                                                       
                                                           '>
                                                       
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                            
                                        
This is my C# Code I can provide more code if you ask.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
            Label lbl = row.FindControl("lblJobCard") as Label;
            ViewState["JobCardCode"] = lbl.Text;
            string lead = GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Modules/Service/Forms/JobCardNew.aspx?JobCardCode=" + GridView1.SelectedValue);

    }
```

I have added some Jquery code for paging and Searching in Grid.

```
function GetCustomers(pageIndex) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "JC.aspx/GetCustomers",
            data: '{searchTerm: "' + SearchTerm() + '", pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my Gridview Html Code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="JobCardCode"
                            AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                             OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1">   <%----%>                                        

                                        <Columns>

                                            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="JobCardCode" HeaderText="JOB CARD" SortExpression="JobCardCode" ></asp:BoundField>\--%>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Card" >
                                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                                       <asp:Label ID="lblJobCard" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobCardCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                   </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="UserName"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="RegNo" HeaderText="Registration #" SortExpression="RegNo"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EngineNo" HeaderText="Engine #" SortExpression="EngineNo"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChassisNo" HeaderText="Chassis #" SortExpression="ChassisNo"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" HeaderText="Edit" ></asp:CommandField>                                            
                                        </Columns>                                            
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: If you are getting `JobCardCode` from the label of selected row why you need to get it from GridView1.SelectedValue ? Can you show the HTML of GridView1 ?

Comment: I am trying both cases but both are giving me null values.

Comment: I have updated the code you can check it.